# Is there a way force a program to use only 1 thread?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I am benchmarking against an annoying piece of cpp program on linux. The program is a mess and complicated as hell! It automatically does multi-threading, and I wonder if there is any way to force by calling it via something, i.e. taskset, etc to use only 1 thread.

**Edit**: I have tried setting "taskset 01 program arg1 ..." but it doesn't work. I just saw the program using 100 threads!

Comment: @Brett - how? I am not the admin, and there are other people using the server.

Comment: Why do you ask? If you are benchmarking you should run the program in the expected conditions, and apparently for that program it means multi-threading. Perhaps most threads are idle, and the program could run on only one or two cores. So **edit your question** to motivate it more.

Comment: BTW, you are missing a `Linux` tag. Also, why benchmarking your program on only one or two cores is making you unhappy?

Comment: But then, limiting the numbers of *cores* (not threads!) is enough. Perhaps the number of threads might be configurable (at least by recompiling the source).

Comment: not really. The code is very I/O sensitive, so multi-threading is actually producing non-sense results in terms of timings.

Answer (score 3):

To limit a *Linux* process to run on one core use `taskset`. The following is taken from https://serverfault.com/a/32331

```
taskset <affinity mask> -p <process>
```

i.e.

```
taskset 1 -p 12345
```

to set process 12345 to use only processor/core 1

The bitmask can be a list (i.e. 1,3,4 to use cores 1 3 and 4 of a 4+ core system) or a bitmask in hex (0x0000000D the 1,3,4, 0x00000001 for just core 1)

`taskset` is usually in a package called `shedutils`.

Edit: almost forgot... If you want to set the affinity of a new command instead of change it for an existing process, use:

```
taskset <mask> <program> [<arg1>]...[<argN>]
```

Comment: your solution is just for linux, you should write it somewhere.

Comment: have tried setting "taskset 01 program arg1 ..." but it doesn't work. I just saw the program using 41 threads!

Comment: @user3639557 You wrote "... or at least 1 core" in your question, so it's an answer to that.

Comment: @anatolyg fixed the question.

Comment: Yes, taskset controls the number of cores that a process is able to run on. It does not control the number of threads. The code in a program would have to provide the ability to limit the number of threads. For example, if I write a program that spawns a thread, there is no external way to stop that; taskset gives you a way to have all of a program's thread run on a set of cores. It does not and cannot stop a program from running threads.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>(I assume you accept a Linux specific solution)</sup>

On Linux, threads (at least [NPTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library) ones) are created using the [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) syscall. It is documented to fail with

> `EAGAIN` Too many processes are already running; see fork(2).

(In fact, the kernel is scheduling tasks which may be threads or [single-threaded] processes)

You could use [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) with `RLIMIT_NPROC`:

> `RLIMIT_NPROC` The maximum number of processes (or, more precisely on Linux,
>                 **threads**) that can be created for the real user ID of the
>                 calling process.

So I guess that you might use that (perhaps with the `ulimit` bash builtin in the shell running in your terminal) to limit the number of *successfully created* threads (actually "tasks").

But I am not sure it would be a good idea. A well written program would test against failure of [pthread_create(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) (which is internally calling [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html)). A poorly written program would crash.

Maybe that program is using some thread pool and there is some way to limit the size of that pool. BTW, you can run dozens of threads on only two cores -or even a single core- (especially when most of the time the threads are idle, e.g. [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)-ing or waiting for I/O).

<sup>PS. For benchmarking purposes, you probably should care more about limiting the number of cores (with `taskset`) than limiting the number of threads.</sup>

Comment: the program to limit threads is `prlimit --nproc=1 prog [args]`. I've tried to use it with `rsync` and got "fork unavailable... error in IPC" and the end - `rsync` is written not to work as one thread.

Answer (score 1):

If the program tries to spawn threads, there is nothing you can do to stop it - unless the program itself has some command line options that will limit the threads.

Comment: But you *can* restrict those threads to only run on certain cores and you *can* limit the *number* of cores it can run on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a single file rather than specified process, the following format of tasktset command would be helpful:

```bash
taskset 1 file
```